# How can create 360 Render Texture in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

I am trying to make a 360 render texture. While game in play mode, one shephere model show us to what is rendered. I don't want to record video. Just show like a 2d Render Texture.

I am using this shader:

```
Shader “Unlit/Pano360Shader”
{
   Properties
   {
       _MainTex (“Base (RGB)”, 2D) = “white” {}
       _Color (“Main Color”, Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
   }

   SubShader 
   {
      Tags { “RenderType” = “Opaque” }

      //This is used to print the texture inside of the sphere
      Cull Front

      CGPROGRAM
      #pragma surface surf SimpleLambert
      half4 LightingSimpleLambert (SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half atten)
      {
         half4 c;
         c.rgb = s.Albedo;
         return c;
      }

      sampler2D _MainTex;
      struct Input
      {
         float2 uv_MainTex;
         float4 myColor : COLOR;
      };

      fixed3 _Color;
      void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
      {
         //This is used to mirror the image correctly when printing it inside of the sphere
         IN.uv_MainTex.x = 1 — IN.uv_MainTex.x;
         fixed3 result = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex)*_Color;
         o.Albedo = result.rgb;
         o.Alpha = 1;
      }
      ENDCG
   }
   Fallback “Diffuse”
}
```

I copied there -> https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-make-a-360%C2%BA-image-viewer-with-unity3d-b1aa9f99cabb

It is working but it show me just photo. When I try to render texture it didn't show anything.
How can create 360 Render Texture in Unity?

Answer (score 2):

Unity cameras can render to cubemap textures. No custom shader is needed.

You need to create an render texture, set it to cubemap:

[image: create RT]

[image: cubemap RT]

And create a simple script on the camera:

```
public class RenderCameraToCubemap : Monobehaviour {
  public RenderTexture rt;
  void LateUpdate() {
    GetComponent<Camera>().RenderToCubemap(rt);
  }
}
```

Warning: UI will not be rendered (known bug).

Comment: I use your solition but i failed.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my question like this;

- 1- Create 2 RendererTexture type of Cube. Set size 1024*1024.
- 2- Create 1 Renderer Texture type of 2D. Set size 1024*1024.
- 3- Create a script name like RenderCamera and add script to camera.

this is Camera code;

```
public RenderTexture cubemapLeft;
public RenderTexture cubemapRight;
public RenderTexture equirect;
public bool renderStereo = true;
public float stereoSeparation = 0.064f;

void LateUpdate()
{
    Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();

    if (cam == null)
    {
        cam = GetComponentInParent<Camera>();
    }

    if (cam == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("stereo 360 capture node has no camera or parent camera");
    }

    if (renderStereo)
    {
        cam.stereoSeparation = stereoSeparation;
        cam.RenderToCubemap(cubemapLeft, 63, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Left);
        cam.RenderToCubemap(cubemapRight, 63, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Right);
    }
    else
    {
        cam.RenderToCubemap(cubemapLeft, 63, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Mono);
    }

    //optional: convert cubemaps to equirect

    if (equirect == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (renderStereo)
    {
        cubemapLeft.ConvertToEquirect(equirect, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Left);
        cubemapRight.ConvertToEquirect(equirect, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Right);
    }
    else
    {
        cubemapLeft.ConvertToEquirect(equirect, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Mono);
    }
}
```

- 4- Create a empty shephere. And write a script for using
  RenderTexture.

This is code:

```
public RenderTexture rt;
public Renderer renderer;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", rt);
}
```

Camera script has lefteye and righteye. Use renderer texture type of Cube and Camera script has a value name is equirect. Use that for 2D renderer texture. and use 2D renderer texture for Shephere script. And Shephere material tilling value is must be x: 1 y:0.5

this is my solution. **I didn't write these codes.**